Rotate a path without twisting object constrained to it
I have an object following a path (using a Curve modifier) in a certain orientation. When I rotate the path, the object does not keep the same angle with the path normals. Is there an easy way to keep the angle fixed and the object aligned when the path is rotated, scaled, or modified?
I am doing this in Blender 4.2
Video: https://somup.com/cZQqXsmGD6


Hard to know from just this limited information. Is the path a curve? Do you have Twist Method set to Z-Up for the curve? What do you mean by "rotate the path"? Twisting it? rotating points in a plane? Is it a Bezier curve, and what happens with the handles with you "rotate"?

Oh sorry, the path is a curve (arc). As far as I can tell there are no handles, and I am not touching them, but I want to rotate the arc with the object, and when I rotate it (just using r x, for example), the arc rotates with the object but the object gets rotated relative to the arc, so I have to correct that rotation by rotating the object back relative to the arc. I just checked and the twist-method of the arc is set to 'Minimum'. If I set it to 'Z-Up' or 'Tangent' I have the same behavior.

I’m afraid you’ll need to provide a video or animation of what you are doing and seeing. Maybe it makes sense to someone else, but not me. Perhaps you could attach a sample blender file with simple instructions to recreate.

Sorry if this was not clear, I made a short video here: link
and here is the Blender file that has the arc and the object that I'd like to rotate:
link
Thank you so much for your willingness to look into this!

Never mind, I figured it out: if I put the arrow and the object into a collection, I can rotate and scale them as a group. Sorry if this was a trivial question, please close the issue

I think it was actually a good question! See my answer for why putting them both in a group makes it work (because you're rotating the up-axis of the geometry at the same time). If you feel the answer helped, I'd appreciate an up-vote (or the accept mark).

Definitely, thank you! I cannot upvote yet (need reputation 15), but as soon as I have it I can up-vote, but I accepted the answer. Thank you for taking the time!

Alternatively, if you convert the curve to be 3D:

And then edit the curve, and select all the vertices, you can twist them to change the local up for the curve:


I don't think this is possible rotating just the curve, by design. Before you apply the modifier, the arrow's body is vertical:

The curve modifier is set to modify the object along its X axis, before rotation. So, when you apply it, the up-axis of the arrow remains up:

So, if you imagine that the curve is rotated before applying the modifier, it makes sense what happens when the modifier is applied; the curve is modifying the arrow in the xz plane, staying tall along the global z axis:


So, the answer is that you have to rotate the arrow model to have the up-axis you want. Here I've removed the rotation.x on the arrow:

If you select BOTH the curve and the arrow, and rotate them both along the x axis, you get the desire you want in this specific case.

